# How to see where an item is used on Sharepoint Site?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have many files (images etc.) in different libraries and I'm not sure which of them I am using / are linked within my Sharepoint site.

Like for example I imagine something like this:

```
example.jpg  - used in: /SitePages/page1.html, /SitePages/page2.html
example.docx - used in: /MyList/
example2.jpg - used in: -
example3.jpg - used in: -
```

I know that for example hyperlinks change automatically when renaming a page. So there seems to be information about the links within the site...

Is there something similar to see if an item is linked/used on the site like in the example above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything in the api that will automatically tell you where a file is being referenced. Something like that would require code that checks for the item that you're looking for which would be easier in a list but a challenge if it appears in the markup or a content editor webpart.